# Group with fewer than $p^2$ Sylow p-subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

(This question is [originally from Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3859476) where it was suggested that I ask the question here)

Let $G$ be a finite group with fewer than $p^2$ Sylow $p$-subgroups, and let $p^n$ be the power of $p$ dividing $\lvert G\rvert$. I can show that if $P$ and $Q$ are any two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ then $\lvert P\cap Q\rvert=p^{n-1}$. I was wondering if this intersection is necessarily the same across all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

> Is the intersection $P\cap Q$ the same for any two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups $P$ and $Q$?

We might as well assume that $G$ has more than one Sylow $p$-subgroup, in which case here are two equivalent formulations:

> Does the intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ necessarily have order $p^{n-1}$?

> Must there exist a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^{n-1}$?

I'm looking for a proof or counterexample of this conjecture.

I know that the conjecture holds in the case where $G$ has $p+1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups.

There is some good partial progress in the comments and answers of the Math.SE link.

Comment: As I commented in the MSE post, I believe that $N_G(P)$ must be a maximal subgroup of $G$, since $N_G(P) < M < G$ would make it impossible for $G$ to have less than $p^2$ Sylow $p$-subgroups. So the conjugation action of $G$ on the Sylow $p$-subgroups is primitive, and we can apply the O'Nan-Scott Theorem. I haven't thought it through, but I am guessing that we can reduce to the almost simple case, and then of course one could resort to the classification.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The conjecture follows quickly from **Brodkey's Theorem**: Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime. Suppose that Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are abelian. If $O_p(G)=1$, then there exist Sylow $p$-subgroups $P$ and $Q$ of $G$ such that $P\cap Q=1$.

Here $O_p(G)$ is the intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, or equivalently the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$. (Note that $O_p(G/O_p(G))=1$.) Brodkey's theorem can be found several places on the web. It is an exercise in section 1E of Isaacs's **Finite Group Theory**.

Now, your assumption implies that $\Phi(P)\le P\cap Q\le Q$ for all Sylow $p$-subgroups $P,Q$ of $G$, so $\Phi(P)\le O_p(G)$. Pass to $\bar G=G/O_p(G)$. Then $\bar P$ is an (elementary) abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\bar G$, and $O_p(\bar G)=1$. (This much was already noted on Math.SE.) Now Brodkey's Theorem gives you $\bar P\cap \bar Q=\bar 1$ for some Sylow subgroups $P,Q$ of $G$, so $P\cap Q=O_p(G)$, as you conjectured.

Comment: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/blms/4.3.377 gives a nice generalization by T. Laffey of the Theorem of J. Brodkey. Laffey proves that if $O_{p}(G) = 1$ and $R,S$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ with $R \cap S$ minimal, then $Z(R) \cap Z(S) = 1$. But Brodkey's Theorem is very elegant and enough for this problem.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Thanks for that. Another generalization is Theorem 1.38 in Isaacs's book: If $R$ and $S$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ with $R\cap S$ minimal, then $O_p(G)=O_p(\langle R,S\rangle)$.

Comment: Title of @GeoffRobinson's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373906/group-with-fewer-than-p2-sylow-p-subgroups#comment946581_373912):  [Laffey - A remark on minimal Sylow intersections](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/4.3.377).

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand things better, let me also give a direct proof (using essentially the same idea as Brodkey's theorem).

Let $P,Q,R$ be Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, let $N=N_G(P\cap Q)$. We know that $P\cap Q$ has order $p^{n-1}$, so $P\leq N$ and $Q\leq N$. In other words, $P$ and $Q$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$.
The intersection $R\cap N$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N$, so $R\cap N\leq P^g$ for some $g\in N$. We have
$$R\cap Q^g=R\cap(N\cap Q^g)=(R\cap N)\cap Q^g\leq P^g\cap Q^g=(P\cap Q)^g=P\cap Q.$$
Now suppose that $P\neq Q$. Then $P\cap Q$ has order $p^{n-1}$, so $R\cap Q^g$ must also have order $p^{n-1}$, and in fact we must have $R\cap Q^g=P\cap Q$. Thus, $P\cap Q\leq R$.
But $R$ is any arbitrary Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, so the conjecture is proven.